# Renaming/moving attachments using VB - Filenameincrement

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, vba, attachments

This script may seem familiar because I took this copy from Superuser (or Stackoverflow) and changed it to suit my needs. The script moves Outlook items around, copies the attachment to a folder and then prints all of the attachments. It's extremely useful as my users generally print hundreds of attachments each day, it's a huge timesaver.

One issue I am having is with Filenameincrementer. It keeps renaming my files the following way:

File.pdf1
File.pdf2
File.pdf3
File.pdf4

While I want:

File1.pdf
File2.pdf
File3.pdf
File4.pdf

What can I do to achieve this?

Disclaimer: First time dabbling with VB, so be gentle.

```
Public Sub PrintPDFs()
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As MailItem
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Filenameincrementer As Integer
Filenameincrementer = 1

Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Item("MAIL_INCOMING")

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
FileName = "X:\Folder\" & Atmt.FileName & Filenameincrementer
Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
Shell """C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe"" -p """ + FileName + """", vbHide
Filenameincrementer = Filenameincrementer + 1
Next
Item.Move GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Item("MAIL_PRINTED")
Next

Set Inbox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this only for PDF?

Comment: This is a nice question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a hack if it suffices. Since `.pdf` is quite unique, we can just search for it, remove it, and then add it on the end.

```
FileName = "X:\Folder\" & Atmt.FileName & Filenameincrementer 'remains the same
FileName = Replace(FileName, ".pdf", "") & ".pdf" ' I'm a new line of code. Hurray
Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName 'remains the same
```

I can't test that but it should work fine...

Comment: or more simply `FileName = "X:\Folder\" & replace(Atmt.Filename,".PDF", Fileincrementer & ".PDF")`